# Wrong user in "File is locked for editing by another user"

Tags: microsoft-office, cifs

We use CIFS shares to store data including Microsoft Office files.

If user tries to open Microsoft Office file which is already opened by another user, there is a message `Filename is locked for editing by 'user'` but in this message the information about user is not correct.

So the **information that file is locked is correct**.

But the **information about user who locked the file is NOT correct**.

What could be the reason for that ?

Where is this information about the user who locked the file coming ?

How to correct this information ?